# Lift error value to ErrorT monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I think I'm missing some basic understanding of monad transformers, because I found myself writing this code:

```
import Control.Monad.Identity
import Control.Monad.Error

liftError :: Either String Int -> ErrorT String Identity Int
liftError x = do case x of
                    Right val -> return val
                    Left err -> throwError err

gateway :: Bool -> ErrorT String Identity Int
gateway = liftError . inner

inner :: Bool -> Either String Int
inner True = return 5
inner False = throwError "test"
```

While this works, I think that this could be done more elegantly. In particular, I'm looking for a replacement of `liftError`, which I think I shouldn't have to define for myself.

What would be the most straightforward way to make `gateway` and `inner` work together without changing their type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just change the types a little, you don't have to do any lifting at all.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

gateway :: Bool -> ErrorT String Identity Int
gateway = inner

inner :: MonadError String m => Bool -> m Int
inner True = return 5
inner False = throwError "test"
```

`MonadError` has instances for both `ErrorT` and `Either`, so this way you can use `inner` as both.

Comment: Okay, so to be more specific, I have to write a manual lifting function if I want to leave the types as they are? This is just for my understanding. BTW unfortunately I can't vote anymore today :/ You will get the vote tomorrow :)

Comment: Without changing the types, you can use `ErrorT . return` in place of your `liftError` function. You could also use the more general version internally and only expose a copy of `inner` with the restricted type.

Comment: That `ErrorT . return` was exactly what I was looking for. As I mentioned, this has nothing to do with any real code, I just want to understand the concept of monad transformers :)